# EF 6.0.2 Data Model Wizard will not populate with tables

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I'm having a strange issue. I added EF 6 to one of my new projects, and added my database connection. Test connection was successful, but where the list of Tables/Views and Stored Procedure are supposed to be, there is nothing. Just three checkboxes that I cannot check. The treeview will not expand with my tables. I went back to an older project that I know works, and attempted to add a table from the designer, same problem!!!

Has anyone else experienced this problem? I installed the latest tools from here http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40762

[EDIT]

Please forgive my stupidity... What I had done was export data from one database (using integrated security) to another database. I then connected to that database using a login I had created for it. The problem was that the table was not visible to that logged in user. I have since resolved the issue. My Bad.

Comment: Please provide more info: Visual Studio, version? Are you upgrading from previous version of EF?

Comment: Both my 2012 and 2013 installs are affected. I had version 6.0 already installed. I created a new project with 6.0.2 and then this happened. And somehow, also my 2012 install is affected. A project I know for a fact worked because there are tables added.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what I had done wrong. See my edit to the original question.